# Write image to Windows clipboard in python with PIL and win32clipboard?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pywin32

I'm trying to open an image file and copy the image to the Windows clipboard.  Is there a way to fix this:

```
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data): 
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data) 
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

clip_type = win32clipboard.CF_BITMAP
filepath = 'c:\\temp\\image.jpg'

im = Image.open(filepath) 
data = im.tobitmap() # fails with valueerror: not a bitmap
# data = im.tostring() runs, but receiving programs can't read the results
send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data)
```

I could install PythonMagick, etc., but would prefer not installing yet another library for a one-off program

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

filepath = 'image.jpg'
image = Image.open(filepath)

output = StringIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

Comment: Why the magic number 14? Will it break on Python 3 or 64 bit Python? Many thanks for an extremely useful answer.

Comment: @MichaelPlatings 14 because a BMP file has a 14-byte header. This header remains 14 bytes whether the BMP file is copied to a 32-bit or 64-bit system. Under Python 3 you need to change `StringIO` to `BytesIO`.

Comment: For python 3, need to modify two lines as follows - 

`from io import BytesIO`
...
`output = BytesIO()`

Comment: @DamianYerrick What is the value for PNG?

Comment: @CoolCloud See yfyang's answer. PNG's header is 8 bytes but Windows clipboard doesn't use PNG.

Answer (score 1):

The file header off-set of BMP is 14 bytes. Well, BMP is also known as the *device independent bitmap (DIB) file format*, so you don't need to worried about the magic number 14.

FYI, it does need a windows clipboard API. Hence you can use BMP but can't use

```
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "PNG")
data = output.getvalue()[8:]
```

even you know the offset is 8 for PNG.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Python 3.8 ([solution found here](https://tousu.in/qa/?qa=741540/&show=741541#a741541))

It's the same answer as the cgohike's but:

```
output = StringIO()
```

changed into:

```
output = io.BytesIO()
```

Full code:

```
import io
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

image = Image.open('image.jpg')

output = io.BytesIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Addendum to the other answers, it's also possible to copy PNG (and probably other formats) to the clipboard. I've used the following:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
img_out.save(fp=buffer, format='PNG')

clipboard_format = win32clipboard.RegisterClipboardFormat('PNG')
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clipboard_format, buffer.getvalue())
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

buffer.close()
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15691001/20318488) to a related question details support by some programs for the non-standard clipboard format "PNG", which I used in my answer. If the program you want to copy to accepts a custom clipboard format, this is an alternative. You can also of course define many standard and/or non-standard clipboard formats together.