# copy image to clipboard in python

Tags: python, image, clipboard

the question is:

**i have a JPG file. i want to use python to copy that image to clip board. how ?**

if you give me a link about image objects in python , it would be appreciated.

thanks

p.s. : system is windows

Comment: I'm sure there's some dependancy on the system you're using.. Linux, Mac, Windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050448/write-image-to-windows-clipboard-in-python-with-pil-and-win32clipboard

Comment: @Amyth thanks man. i found the answer there.