# How can I make a file copying script in python?

Tags: python, image

I want to make a python script that grabs the newest file from a given directory (always going to be an image file) and copy that image to my clipboard. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered here -

- [How to get the latest file in a folder using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327032/how-to-get-the-latest-file-in-a-folder-using-python)
- [Copy image to clipboard in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322132/copy-image-to-clipboard-in-python3)

I am just putting it altogether.

```
import glob
import os
from cStringIO import StringIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*')
newest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
image = Image.open(newest_file)

output = StringIO()
image.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:] # BMP file has a 14-byte header
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

Comment: What if I'm on Windows? They don't store clipboard in a folder, so is copying it to my clipboard still achievable? Basically I just want it to grab the image and copy it so I can paste it somewhere