# I want to copy an image and text to my clipboard in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipboard

I used code by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322132/copy-image-to-clipboard) question and this is what I have:

```
from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.jpg')
output = BytesIO()
image.convert('RGB').save(output, 'BMP')
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

now what should I do if I wanna copy the word 'hello' before the image go down one line and then the image

I tried doing this

```
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB,BytesIO(StringIO('hello_world' + '\n').read().encode('utf8')) + data)
```

but it gave me:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: '_io.BytesIO' and 'bytes'

Comment: win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB,BytesIO(StringIO(f'hello_world "\n" {data}').read().encode('utf8'))

Answer (score 0):

Get the [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) from the `BytesIO`

```
BytesIO(StringIO('hello_world' + '\n').read().encode('utf8')).getvalue() + data
```

But really it's just either of the following

```
'hello_world\n'.encode('utf8') + data
b'hello_world\n' + data
```

Comment: when I try and paste it it just shows me the picture can't be displayed

Comment: @ZombZ how can you expect the image viewer to display a wrong file image ? You have broken it by putting bytes that shouldn't be here