# How save multiple picture in clipboard

Tags: python, image, clipboard, bytesio

On window when you select multiples image in a folder and press "Ctrl + V" all the images will store in clipboard after you can paste to Messenger or other chat app. So there are any way to me store multiple images in clipboard using python code.

I using BytesIO to store image and get value from that to copy to clipboard but i just can store 1 image

Comment: Can you send a testable code and told us what have you tried for now?

Comment: I try following this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322132/copy-image-to-clipboard. this code just for copy 1 image, I don't have no idea for copy multiple

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: clipboard images and clipboard files are different things. clipboard supports only a single image, but there are options to put multiple files in clipboard (which is just the filenames)

Comment: You might get some ideas by reading the source code of `CopyQ` here https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line.html

Comment: thanks for all reply, I will check and try again