# Copy multiple images to clipboard in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, clipboarddata, clipboard-pictures

Using Python 3.4.0 in Windows 7, I've managed to copy a single image to clipboard thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319486/copy-pil-pillow-image-to-windows-clipboard).

Now I want to copy multiple images at the same time.
I don't understand much of what is happening in this code, so I'm unable to modify it.
Any ideas?

My code:

```
    msvcrt = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    CF_DIB = 8
    GMEM_MOVEABLE = 0x0002
    user32.OpenClipboard(None)
    user32.EmptyClipboard()

    for image_path in list:
        img = Image.open(image_path)

        output = io.BytesIO()
        img.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
        data = output.getvalue()[14:]
        output.close()

        global_mem = kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len(data))
        global_data = kernel32.GlobalLock(global_mem)
        msvcrt.memcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(global_data), data, len(data))
        kernel32.GlobalUnlock(global_mem)
        user32.SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, global_mem)

    user32.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: How is the "pasting" program supposed to access these multiple images?

Comment: What application are you trying to paste these images into?

Comment: I'm trying to paste these multiple images in Microsoft Word.
My doubt is how to copy those images to clipboard like it is copied inside Word.
It should access the images by a simple "ctrl+v".  =)