# Substitute string in .docx file by jpg with python

Tags: python

Sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to substitute a string in .docx file by a .jpg file. First I convert JPEG to BMP and move it to clipboard follow [Copy PIL/PILLOW Image to Windows Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319486/copy-pil-pillow-image-to-windows-clipboard), then use Find.Execute with "^c" to substitute a special string in docx file.

The substitution works well, but it paste a image with width of 15.42cm to the .docx file. I've tried to resize it with im.resize, but it ends with a large blur image rather than a small one. How could I make it smaller?

I'm using python2.7.2 and Win7. Thanks a lot.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from cStringIO import StringIO
import win32clipboard
import win32com
from PIL import Image

def setImageToClipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

filepath = 'd:/tmp.jpg'
im = Image.open(filepath)
#im = im.resize((10, 10))

output = StringIO()
im.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[14:]
output.close()

w = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
w.Visible = 1
w.DisplayAlerts = 0
doc = w.Documents.Open("d:/clipboard_test.docx")

search = "TEST"

setImageToClipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
w.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
w.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
w.Selection.Find.Execute("TEST", False, True, False, False, False, True, 1, True, ReplaceWith="^c", Replace=2000)

doc.SaveAs("d:/clipboard_test2.docx")
doc.Close()
w.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much more cleanly and without actually needing MS-Word installed or starting it up by using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You will need to read in your existing document, find the text that you need to replace and then use `document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))`
 rather than using word and pretending to paint.

The only other option is to have python select the image that you have pasted and set its properties within word.