# Copying from clipboard using tkinter without displaying window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard, pywin32

Running Python 3.4 on Windows 7.

I need to copy what's stored in the clipboard to a variable in my python program.  I've seen on Stack Overflow that that can be done either with `pywin32` or `tkinter`.  Since `tkinter` is part of the python standard library, I decided that that was the better of the two since the user won't have to install an external module.  Here's the code for getting the clipboard data in `tkinter`:

```
import tkinter
number = tkinter.Tk().clipboard_get()
```

This works fine except a blank `tkinter` window pops up every time this executes.

1. Why is this happening?  Normally `tkinter` doesn't display anything until `tk().mainloop()` is run.
2. Is there any way to avoid this window popping up?  If not, I guess I'll just use `pywin32`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window is created by `tkinter.Tk()` (or other elements which need window) not by `tk().mainloop()`. Mainloop keeps program working.

Maybe try [Pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/) or [clipboard](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/0.0.4)

Comment: those two modules are great thanks.  Do you know why the paste() returns a byte object instead of a string?

Comment: I use Python 2.7 on Linux Mint and I get string. Probably it depends on system.

Comment: Interesting.  Python 3.4 on Windows 7 gives a byte object.  I just converted it to utf-8 string

Answer (score 21):

> This works fine except a blank tkinter window pops up every time this executes.

You can hide this window:

```
from tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
number = root.clipboard_get()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Python function based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python/4203897#4203897) that replaces/returns clipboard text using *Tkinter*, a built-in Python module, without showing the window.

```
def use_clipboard(paste_text=None):
    import tkinter # For Python 2, replace with "import Tkinter as tkinter".
    tk = tkinter.Tk()
    tk.withdraw()
    if type(paste_text) == str: # Set clipboard text.
        tk.clipboard_clear()
        tk.clipboard_append(paste_text)
    try:
        clipboard_text = tk.clipboard_get()
    except tkinter.TclError:
        clipboard_text = ''
    r.update() # Stops a few errors (clipboard text unchanged, command line program unresponsive, window not destroyed).
    tk.destroy()
    return clipboard_text
```

A small disadvantage with using this Tkinter based method is that it uses a quickly hidden window which isn't ideal but this shouldn't be noticeable.
*This answer uses content from my original answer on the Stack Overflow question [How to copy/get an image in the clipboard with Python (I accept Tkinter for text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474536/how-to-copy-get-an-image-in-the-clipboard-with-python-i-accept-tkinter-for-text).*

Comment: You don't define `r in` this answer. Presumably `tk.update()` is the correct line

Answer (score 2):

```
AnnoyingWindow = Tk()
ClipBoard = AnnoyingWindow.clipboard_get()
AnnoyingWindow.destroy()
print(ClipBoard)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This worked for me on windows 7, python 2.7.  I now only get one window.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
cliptext = root.clipboard_get()
lab=Label(root, text = cliptext)
lab.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number.withdraw() #this hides the ui for the object
```

Just add this command at the beginning when you create your TKinter object and it will hide the UI.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python?rq=1) similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it without `tkinter` and in a much more simple way with a non-default module called `pyperclip`.

Install with:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Usage:

```
import pyperclip

clipboard_content = pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: Good but not a default module

Answer (score 0):

A tkinter way without window:

```
from tkinter import Tk


def clipboard_get():
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    return r.clipboard_get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two simple lines

It works in Windows & Linux (shall work cross platform as explained below)

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Paste clipboard (get clipboard content and assign to variable data)

data = sg.clipboard_get()


# Copy clipboard (send string from variable text to clipboard)

text = 'My text to clipboard'
sg.clipboard_set(text)
```

This does not requires you to open/hide any window and it uses Tkinter in fact you may want to take a look to PySimpleGUI which is far easier than Tkinter, has a lot of documentation with so many examples that in minutes you can start having your own GUI design.

> It's surprising that Python GUI code is completely cross platform from Windows to Mac to Linux. No source code changes. This is true for both PySimpleGUI and PySimpleGUIQt
> https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#tkinter-version