# How can I send an image to the clipboard in python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, clipboard, pyautogui

I'm trying to use some images I take using pillow and that I organize in a list.

I would like to send those images to the clipboard, so I can use 'ctrl v' to manage those images in several word documents.

Right now, what I do is sending those images to an open word file using win32, so there's no useful code to show... but the images are in lists like:

```
[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=281x164 at 0x2A46AAAB7F0>]
```

I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Explore modules/libraries such as: tkinter, pyperclip, clipboard, xerox.

These questions may be of use to dig through:

- [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python/4203897#4203897)
- [Python Script to Copy Text to Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063458/python-script-to-copy-text-to-clipboard)
- [How to Add/Get Image
  Data in the OS Clipboard using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474536/how-to-add-get-image-data-in-the-os-clipboard-using-python)